# sql concatenation with blank cells

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am extracting data from one table to another

```
SELECT *            

        LTRIM(ADRESSE + ',' + ADRESSE2)  AS ADDRESS12

FROM [Homestore].[dbo].[CLIENT]
```

Issue is that if the cells are blank i still get a comma , 
I have tried using & instead of + but nvarchar is incompatible in the '&' operator. Any ideas how I only insert the comma if there is something to concatenate?

Answer (score 3):

You want the equivalent of `CONCAT_WS()` in other databases.  You can do this with `STUFF()` and some string logic in SQL Server:

```
SELECT c.*
       STUFF( (COALESCE(',' + ADRESSE, '') +
               COALESCE(',' + ADRESSE2, '') +
              ), 1, 1, ''
             ) AS ADDRESS12
FROM [Homestore].[dbo].[CLIENT] c;
```

This structure is convenient, because you can just add more `COALESCE()` expressions for more columns.

Answer (score 0):

use `case` expression

```
SELECT *, LTRIM(ADRESSE + case when ADRESSE is not null then ',' end + ADRESSE2)  AS ADDRESS12
FROM [Homestore].[dbo].[CLIENT]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `case when` for null checking

```
 SELECT *            

            LTRIM(ADRESSE + case when ADRESSE2 is not null then
   ',' else '' end + ADRESSE2)  AS ADDRESS12

    FROM [Homestore].[dbo].[CLIENT]
```